# <JSP,JQuery> can anyone explain this simple code?

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

fnSelGrp = function(id, nm, exp){

    $('#A').val(id);
    $('#B').val(nm);
    $('#C').val(exp);

    $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",   
        url: "${innovativepot}/sysMng/codeList",   
        async: false, 
        data: "cdGrpId="+id,   
        success: function(result){   
            $('#codeList').html(result);   
        },
        error: function(result, status, error){
            alert('<spring:message code="data.error"/>');   
        }
    });
.
.
.
.
 <c:forEach items="${resultList.content}" var="result" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkGrp" name="chkGrp" value="${result.A}"/></td>
    <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="fnSelGrp('${result.A}', '${result.B}', '${result.C}')">${result.A}</td>
    <td>${result.B}</td>
    <td>${result.C}</td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

So I understand that this displays a chart with checkbox one the left. And it displays A,B,C from the "resultList.content". 
But here are my questions.

1) what does

```
<td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="fnSelGrp('${result.A}', '${result.B}', '${result.C}')">${result.A}</td> mean?
```

2) In this code,

```
fnSelGrp = function(id, nm, exp){

    $('#A').val(id);
    $('#B').val(nm);
    $('#C').val(exp);
```

what does it mean? Value of A becomes id? 
And it displays its data in #CodeList, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Values `${result.A}, ${result.B}, ${result.C}` will be passed into `JS` function when you click specified `TD`. `fnSelGrp` function will be called.
2) `$('#A').val(id);` - the value of html element with `id = "A"` will be set = `id`. In your case `id` will equal `${result.A}`. Result of ajax call (as HTML output) will be passed into `#CodeList` element.